# How to override __iter__ and __contains__ statically?

Tags: python, class, iterator

I have this code I wrote, to go through all of the primes and print them out.

```
class Primes:

  def __contains__(self, num):
    for divd in range(2, num):
      if num % divd == 0:
        return False
    return True

  def __iter__(self):
    yield 2
    count = 3
    while True:
      if count in self:
        yield count
      count += 2

primes = Primes()
for x in primes:
  print(x)
```

It works fine, but it bugs me that I have to create a Primes object in order to iterate over it. It would make more sense if the second to last line was `for x in Primes:` and the other line was `if count in Primes`, but adding either the @classmethod or @staticmethod decorator gives me a `argument of type 'classobj' is not iterable` error. What's the actual way to do this?

Comment: You can just do `for x in Primes():`. Or is that still a problem?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but if you're getting `argument of type 'classobj' is not iterable` then you're not using Python 3.  'classobj' only exists in Python 2 and is the type of old-style classes.

Comment: Why not just have some sort of custom `Math` class with a `@staticmethod` `def primes():` ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Iguana, I deleted that comment.

Comment: @Trengot: That still involves the overhead of creating an instance of the class, which is unnecessary since neither of the methods use any instance variables.

Comment: @JoshuaSnider: then why use a class *at all*?

Comment: @JoshuaSnider: and using any other generator also requires creating the generator; a `def primes()` function using `yield` would *still need to be called*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python [looks up special methods on the *type* of the object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup). To iterate over a class, you'd have to put the `__iter__` method on the *metaclass*.

Just create the instance in the `for` loop:

```
for x in Primes():
```

as creating a metaclass just to produce prime numbers is just too much indirection. It would look like this:

```
class PrimesMeta(type):
    def __contains__(self, num):
        # more efficient prime number test
        if num % 2 == 0:  # even
            return False
        for divd in range(3, int(num ** 0.5) + 1, 2):
            if num % divd == 0:
                return False
        return True

    def __iter__(self):
        yield 2
        count = 3
        while True:
            if count in self:
                yield count
            count += 2

class Primes(metaclass=PrimesMeta):
    pass
```

For Python 2, you'd create `Primes` with:

```
class Primes(object):
    __metaclass__ = PrimesMeta
```

instead.

You can improve on the generator further by using a sieve; see http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117119/ for an excellent infinite generator implementation.